# FCM notification is not received when sent from firebase notification console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase notifications in my application. I have performed all steps mentioned in firebase documentaton. I can also receive the registration token inside onTokenRefresh() method. But when I try to send message to my device from Firebase Notification console, It shows status as 'Completed' next to message, but I don't receive anything on my device even when app is in background.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I don't receive anything", what do you expect?

Comment: Apparently there was a mistake in my manifest file.I had added same action in both(FirebaseMessagingService and FirebaseInstanceIdService). while looking closely I got it. thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Happy you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

(copy paste from my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798898/5284370))

I had this exact problem, the device behavior was somehow weird. some notifications were received, some not.

In the end I found out what was wrong. My device's Sync setting was off. please check that first and don't waste your time like me. [image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to call 
private void sendNotification(String topic); method from Overriden method public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage). then your notification will added to notification bar.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I have implemented private void sendNotification(String messageBody). But I expect to receive notification insystem tray when app is in background as I am sending notifications from notification console.